# PHP get day N by this date format

Tags: php

```
$myDate = "30-Aug-2014";
$which_day = date('N',$myDate);
echo "Which Day > " . $which_day;
```

The return was

```
Which Day > 4
```

But result should be 6 as it was saturday :) How do I change to make my code return a 6 which is the actual answer. My date format in database is not unix time and is in varchar format of

```
d-M-Y
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it to timestamp first using `strtotime()`, then feed it into the `date()` function. Exmaple:

```
$myDate = "30-Aug-2014";
$which_day = date('N', strtotime($myDate));
                        // ^
echo "Which Day > " . $which_day; // Which Day > 6
```

Or you can also use `DateTime`:

```
$myDate = "30-Aug-2014";
$which_day = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y', $myDate);
echo "Which Day > " . $which_day->format('N');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use strtotime() and date():

```
$myDate = "30-Aug-2014";
$which_day = date('N',strtotime($myDate));
echo "Which Day > " . $which_day;
```